# jQuery fadeOut a variable and normal element not working

Tags: jquery, variables, css-selectors, fadeout

I'm trying to fadeout a variable and normal element. Independently they do fadeout but not together. What am I doing wrong?

doesn't work(i've tried the combinations I could find or came to mind):

```
    var action = $(this).find('.min, .close');
    $('#nav ul,'+action+'').fadeOut("fast");
```

does work:

```
    $(this).find('.min, .close').fadeOut("fast");
    $('#nav ul').fadeOut("fast");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var action = $(this).find('.min, .close');
action.add('#nav ul').fadeOut("fast");
```